# Is there a way of extracting game info from sc2?

Tags: starcraft-2

[Knowing that Blizzard is teaming up with DeepMind to develop an API for bots in Starcraft 2](https://deepmind.com/blog/deepmind-and-blizzard-release-starcraft-ii-ai-research-environment/), I was wondering if there's a way of extracting the scorescreen info from games (i.e. the graphs about army size, the build order, the stats about research and such) or even from replays?. **Does anybody know a way?** Such info would be gold when it comes to training a neural network.

Comment: AFAIK, there was no announcement of public API in Starcraft II client one could use to monitor games. All the data, though, is present in replay files, and there are several replay parsers/analyzers available: see [Google search](https://www.google.ru/search?q=starcraft+2+replay+analyzer) and a [relevant question on Gamedev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10622/104294).

Comment: @OrcJMR I believe you are correct, you could post that as an answer and I would upvote that.

Comment: @OrcJMR the sc2 python library that the answer you linked commented is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!, post your comment as an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @Miguelgondu It'd probably be better if you answer the question yourself - nothing wrong with answering your own question and accepting (as long as this results in a best quality answer for future visitors). You can mention whatever rakes you've already stepped on to help others :-)